# for not running in onPostExecute

Tags: android, arrays

I am getting some info from the server and the `for` used in `onPostExecute` was supposed to store the data into 2 different arrays. The server's response it's alright, it gets to the app, it is recognized as a `JSON` object, but when it comes to transforming it to a `JSONArray` to get the elements it just gets over that part of the code, as it wouldn't be written. So, after the `JSONArray departamenteArray = obj.getJSONArray("departamente");` line, it just goes over the rest of it without making any changes.

.java code:

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            //hiding the progressbar after completion

            try {
                //converting response to json object
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

                //if no error in response
                if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                    JSONArray departamenteArray = obj.getJSONArray("departamente");
                    for (int i = 0; i < departamenteArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dep = departamenteArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Verificare daca s-au primit probleme trimise de server
                        if (!dep.isNull("Departament")) {
                            String departament = SchimbareDiactritice(dep.getString("Departament")).replace("&","");
                            String id_departament= dep.getString("id_departament");
                            id_departamente.add(id_departament);
                            departamente.add(departament);
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            layout_validare.setVisibility(GONE);
            linearLayout_obs_redirectionare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

`JSON` response from the server :

```
{
"error": false,
"message": "Alerte reimprospatate",
"departamente": [{
    "Departament": "Parc&#259;ri",
    "id_departament": 2
}, {
    "Departament": "Trafic rutier &#537;i iluminat public",
    "id_departament": 3
}, {
    "Departament": "Salubritate &#537;i vandalism",
    "id_departament": 4
}, {
    "Departament": "Altele",
    "id_departament": 5
}]
```

}

.php code on the server side:

```
if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
$stmt->bind_result($departament, $id_departament);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $departamente[] = array (
        "Departament"=>$departament,
            "id_departament"=>$id_departament
    );
$response['error'] = false; 
$response['message'] = 'Alerte reimprospatate';
$response['departamente']= $departamente;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that after a restart of the `Android Studio` it works. It must have been only a bug. The code shown above it's working properly.